# Magnetization currents (amperian currents): how to show that they are always zero in total from the definition?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

For magnetic field in matter the two following amperian current densities are  defined:

- Surface currents: u.m. $[\frac{A}{m}]$
  $$J_{A,s}= \bf{M} \times  \hat{n}$$
- Volume currents: u.m. $[\frac{A}{m^2}]$

  $$J_{A,V}= \nabla \times \bf{M}   $$

Where $\bf{M}$ is the magnetization and $\hat{n}$ is the normal outgoing from the object considered.

My question is : how to see, from the definition that the **total amperian current** is zero? I.e., why is

$$I_{A,S}+I_{A,V}=0 \,\,\, \mathrm{everywhere}$$
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're comfortable with delta functions etc., you can prove that the surface current formula is a special case of the volume current formula (the special case where M goes sharply to zero across a boundary). So we really only need the volume current case.

Kelvin-Stokes theorem says
$$\oint_\Gamma \mathbf{M}\, \cdot\, d{\mathbf{\Gamma}}  = \iint_S (\nabla\times\mathbf{M})\, \cdot\, d\mathbf{S}$$
Let's prove the z component of $J$ is zero. (x and y are obviously the same argument.)

Say we have some object of finite extent surrounded by air (air has magnetization zero). For each number $z_0$, we draw a loop in the $z=z_0$ plane, entirely outside the object, and then apply Kelvin-Stokes. The LHS is zero, so the formula says that the integrated z-component of $J_{A,V}$ in this $z=z_0$ slice of the object is zero. If the total in each $z=z_0$ slice is zero, then (by integration) the total in the whole object is also zero.